# How to put multiple scenes in a SpriteKit project

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene, sknode

I am quite new to SpriteKit this is my 5th game I am making. So I'm wondering is it possible to have multiple SKScenes in the first scene.

For eg:

[image]

And if not possible, how do I go about to do this. Please show some codes thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have 2 SKScenes in 1 scene.

You will have to treat it as 2 different scenes or create a menu Sprite/SKNode if that 2nd scene is supposed to overlay information.